# checking null values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
main_df[main_df.isnull()].count()
```

result:

```
number_project           0
average_montly_hours     0
time_spend_company       0
Work_accident            0
left                     0
promotion_last_5years    0
department               0
salary                   0
satisfaction_level       0
last_evaluation          0
dtype: int64
```

however, when I used any() method , I found some null value in my columns

```
main_df.isnull().any()
```

results:

```
number_project           False
average_montly_hours     False
time_spend_company       False
Work_accident            False
left                     False
promotion_last_5years    False
department               False
salary                   False
satisfaction_level        True
last_evaluation           True
dtype: bool
```

why have this situation?

by the way, I also try the sum(), the result was 0.0 as well,
and then

```
main_df[main_df['employee_id'] == 3794]
```

result is

```
18  3794    2   160 3   1   1   1   sales   low NaN NaN
```

however, when I checked by column name

```
main_df[main_df['satisfaction_level'] == np.nan]
```

NO any output!

Comment: Change `main_df[main_df['satisfaction_level'] == np.nan]`  to `main_df[main_df['satisfaction_level'].isna()]`  anything == np.nan always returns False.  Even 'np.nan == np.nan` returns False that is not a good check.

Comment: You also need to verify that you don't have string 'NaN' vs a true np.nan.

Comment: OHH got it, however, what happened to this code ```main_df[main_df.isnull()].count()``` if I wanna check the whole dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
main_df.isna().sum()
```

Describe will also tell you if there are na values

```
main_df.info()
```

Comment: Yeah I also try the sum() the result also was employee_id              0.0
number_project           0.0
average_montly_hours     0.0
time_spend_company       0.0
Work_accident            0.0
left                     0.0
promotion_last_5years    0.0
department               0.0
salary                   0.0
satisfaction_level       0.0
last_evaluation          0.0

Answer (score 0):

print(main_df.isnull().sum()[main_df.isnull().sum()>0])

Comment: Please avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.

Comment: Answer needs supporting information
Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).